# Displaying number of copies and current copy on a Crystal Report page in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, crystal-reports

I would like to print invoices using Crystal Report in WPF that displays the number of copies and the current copy number. Is there a way to achieve this? 

I could include an object from the c# code to show the number of copies, however I find this a bit cumbersome and kind-of overkill. In addition I would still not know the current copy number on my Crystal Report page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following approach to resolve this issue:
I created a variable (`noCopies`) to store the number of copies I want to print and created an other variable (`copyNo`) which holds the current copy number, that shall be also used in the Crystal Reports as a parameter. I used the following snippet:

```
for (copyNo = 1; copyNo <= noCopies; copyNo++)
{
    objRpt.SetParameterValue("copyNo", copyNo);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = objRpt;
    objRpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
    ...
}
```

This way the desired amount of copies shall be printed and also shown correctly on the riport.